# Matlab GA plot in nodisplay mode

Tags: linux, matlab, terminal, plot, save

I'm using the matlab GA and the plot option 'gaplotrange'. But I'm running matlab on a Linux server through a terminal. So when I try to save the gaplot, I either keep getting an empty image (if I use saveas) or an error (if I use print, I get a message saying it is not supported in the current platform).

Is there any other way I could save the plot in the nodisplay mode?

Here is a piece of my code

```
opts = gaoptimset('PopulationSize', 256, 'EliteCount',1,'CrossoverFraction',0.8, ...
 'Generation', 3, 'PenaltyFactor',80,'SelectionFcn',{@selectiontournament,4}, ...
 'CrossoverFcn', @crossoverscattered ,'Vectorized','off', 'UseParallel','always',...
 'OutputFcns',@pop_output,'MutationFcn',{@mutationuniform,0.002},'StallGenLimit',3,...
 'TolFun', 1e-4,'PlotFcns',@gaplotbestf);

f = figure('vis','off');

[x,fval, exitflag, output, population, scores] = ga(@plate_fitness,16,[],[],[],[],vlb,vub,[],opts);

hgsave(f,'matlabga_range','png');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab has a solution for this one [posted here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1KY74I/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1KY74I)

```
hgsave('filename')
hgsave(h,'filename')
```

I don't have much experience with the genetic algorithms toolbox, but a quick glance at the docs shows this

> To display a plot when calling ga from the command line, set the PlotFcns field of options to be a function handle to the plot function. For example, to display the best fitness plot, set options as follows
>
> options = gaoptimset('PlotFcns', @gaplotbestf);

So if you're not passing `'PlotFcns'` with a handle to the plotting function in, it looks like it won't generate the plot based on command line interaction.  Add it in and see if it fixes your problem, more details [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/gads/f6174dfi10.html)

**Update:**

Turns out the problem was that the ga method's plot was creating its own figure, so the save needed to be on the `gcf`, see the discussion below for more details.

Comment: Yes, Another plot option in the 'PlotFcns' is @gaplotrange. Thats the option I'm passing.

Comment: Looking at your code, I'd try two things.  The first is using `gcf` instead of `f` as your figure handle.  It looks to me like ga will create a new plot window rather than modifying gcf.  So you'd make f, save f, but never plot to f.  The other thing I'd consider is playing with the `PlotInterval` option, since I can't see what that defaults to.

Comment: So I tried

gcf =  figure('vis','off');
saveas(gcf,'filename','format');

Still gives an empty image :( However, my friend told me to just retrieve all the data and plot later (locally with display on). So that is what I'm doing right now.

Comment: You definitely *don't* want to say `gcf = figure('vis','off');`.  That overrides `gcf` with a local variable where it is normally a globally accessible variable which stands for "get current figure".  So drop that `gcf=` command

Comment: postscript - if you've already declared `gcf = figure()` in the current session then you need to issue a `clear gcf;` before continuing with the instructions I just gave

Comment: Ok great, I will alter the answer to reflect that the problem involved gcf, go ahead an accept the answer if you're satisfied with it